# Generating an author index with author names only, not dates, using natbib

Tags: natbib, indexing

I'm generating an author index using `natbib`, `makeidx`, and `\citep` and `\citet` in the document, with `\citeindextrue`.  This works, but the author entries are of the form:

> Hegselmann (2001), 142, 190
>
> Hegselmann (2012), 55, 190

What I would like to appear is just:

> Hegselmann, 55, 142, 190

The `natbib` documentation makes an elliptic reference (page 16) to:
"The form of the index entries is set by the internal `\NAT@idxtxt`, which
can be redefined by hackers if wanted (in the `natbib.cfg` file please). By
default, it prints the short author list plus date or number in the current
parenthesis style and citation mode."

I have tried '`\renewcommand\NAT@idxtxt{\NAT@name\NAT@spacechar}`' in the `natbib.cfg` file, but this doesn't seem to work (index entries are unchanged).

What should I be doing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem? It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

`NAT@idxtxt` is redefined each time a cite is generated, so I suggest you change `NAT@index` to use something like `NAT@myidxtxt`. In the preamble you can write:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NAT@index{\@bsphack\begingroup
   \def~{\string~}\@wrindex{\NAT@myidxtxt}}
\newcommand\NAT@myidxtxt{\NAT@name}
\makeatother
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your redefinition of `\NAT@idxtxt` does not work is that `natbib` sets this definition at `\begin{document}`, so your earlier definition is overwritten. Hence we need an end run for the latest definition, using `\AtBeginDocument`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeindex
\citeindextrue

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setNATidxtxt}{%
  \renewcommand\NAT@idxtxt{\NAT@name}
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\setNATidxtxt}

\begin{document}
\citet{StGu92}

\printindex

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Note that I also removed the `\NAT@spacechar` from your definition, as this was used in the original definition to separate names and year.

[image: sample output]